# Selecting 4th child div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a 5th child div under main div which id is main_div but child div's has no id or class.

I am trying to get the text from 4th child "div text 04"

Here is my html:

```
<div id="main_div">
    <div>div 01</div>
    <div>div 02</div>
    <div>div 03</div>
    <div>div text 04</div>
    <div>div 05</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying with this but it's not working because there is no class in child div. How can I get 4th child div text?

```
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
html_soup = soup.find('div', {"id": 'main'})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the structure won't change and all you want it the 4th div then try this, for example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """<div id="main_div">
    <div>div 01</div>
    <div>div 02</div>
    <div>div 03</div>
    <div>div text 04</div>
    <div>div 05</div>
</div>"""

soup = (
    BeautifulSoup(sample_html, 'html.parser')
    .find(id='main_div')
    .find_all('div')[-2]
    .text
)
print(soup)
```

Or use CSS selector:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample_html, 'html.parser')
parent = soup.find(id="main_div")
# assign child value
n = 4
print(parent.select_one("div:nth-of-type(" + str(n) + ")").getText())
```

Output:

```
div text 04
```

Comment: The structure will change. I'm looking for other ways instead indexing

Comment: You don't mention that in your question.

Comment: And what other ways of getting the *fourth* element in a collection than indexing you're thinking of?